# how can client retrieve vector list from server?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, tcp, client-server

i have a client application that needs to connect to servers from anywhere so to do this i'm trying to create a master server. this master server saves the other servers ip addresses in a vector. the client will then get this list of servers and select one to connect to. so basically the master server just needs to pass on the servers addresses to the client

i need my client application to access this vector list from the master server and display the addresses in a listbox

so how can the client access the vector list from the master server?

here is the code from the master server:

```
WSADATA wsaData; 
SOCKET ListeningSocket, NewConnection; 
SOCKADDR_IN ServerAddr, SenderInfo;  quantity
int Port = 7171;
char recvbuff[1024];
int ByteReceived, i, nlen;

ListeningSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

ServerAddr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
ServerAddr.sin_port = htons(Port);
ServerAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

std::vector<std::string> vClientIPs; // client ip string vector
while(1)
{
    NewConnection = SOCKET_ERROR;
    while(NewConnection == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        NewConnection = accept(ListeningSocket, NULL, NULL);
        printf("Server: New client got connected, ready to receive and send data...\n\n");
        ByteReceived = recv(NewConnection, recvbuff, sizeof(recvbuff), 0);

        if ( ByteReceived > 0 )
        {
            getsockname(ListeningSocket, (SOCKADDR *)&ServerAddr, (int *)sizeof(ServerAddr));
            printf("Server: IP(s) used by Server: %s\n", inet_ntoa(ServerAddr.sin_addr)); 
            vClientIPs.push_back(std::string(inet_ntoa(ServerAddr.sin_addr))); //insert client ip
            printf("Server: port used by Server: %d\n\n", htons(ServerAddr.sin_port));
            memset(&SenderInfo, 0, sizeof(SenderInfo));
            nlen = sizeof(SenderInfo);
            getpeername(NewConnection, (SOCKADDR *)&SenderInfo, &nlen);
            printf("Server: IP used by Client: %s\n", inet_ntoa(SenderInfo.sin_addr));
            printf("Server: Port used by Client: %d\n", htons(SenderInfo.sin_port));
            printf("Server: Bytes received: %d\n", ByteReceived);
            printf("Server: Message from client: \"");

            for(i=0;i < ByteReceived;i++)
            {
                printf("%c", recvbuff[i]);
            }
            printf("\"");
            }
            else if ( ByteReceived == 0 )
            {
                printf("Server: Connection closed!\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Server: recv failed with error code: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here is the client code:

```
WSADATA wsaData;
SOCKET SendingSocket;
SOCKADDR_IN ServerAddr, ThisSenderInfo;
unsigned int Port = 7171;
int RetCode;

char sendbuf[1024] = "This is a test string from client";
int BytesSent, nlen;

WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
SendingSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

ServerAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
ServerAddr.sin_port = htons(Port);
ServerAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); 

ClientInfo info;
info.addr = inet_ntoa(ServerAddr.sin_addr); //push address onto listbox

RetCode = connect(SendingSocket, (SOCKADDR *) &ServerAddr, sizeof(ServerAddr));
getsockname(SendingSocket, (SOCKADDR *)&ServerAddr, (int *)sizeof(ServerAddr));

BytesSent = send(SendingSocket, sendbuf, strlen(sendbuf), 0);

if(BytesSent == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    AfxMessageBox("Send error %ld.\n", WSAGetLastError());
}
else
{
    memset(&ThisSenderInfo, 0, sizeof(ThisSenderInfo));
    nlen = sizeof(ThisSenderInfo);

    getsockname(SendingSocket, (SOCKADDR *)&ThisSenderInfo, &nlen);         

}

Mutex<CriticalSection>::Lock lock(client_cs);
clients.push_back(info);
```

right now the client just connects to a server which is on the local machine and it only displays one address (the one i send it to). how can i get the address saved in the vector and display that instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate through the vector on the server side and send the data (raw bytes from each string). Terminate it with double '0' in order to know that you reached the end while receiving on the client side.
I really doubt that you have too much data, but if you have, compress it before sending and decompress it on the other side.

Comment: how would i send/receive the data? the data only needs to be sent when the client application connects to server

Comment: send()/recv()? Maybe in combination with select() if you have non-blocking sockets etc... When new client connects, send him the vector content. That's it.

Comment: what would the send code look like? i tried vClientIPs = send( ListeningSocket, recvbuff, (int)strlen(recvbuff), 0 ); but it doesn't work

Comment: I guess you should send the data to the 'NewConnection' socket. Btw, strlen() will return the size without the terminating NULL character. So, if you have more strings, they will arrive to the client side concatenated. Send the NULL character also, and make sure you have 2 NULL characters at the end. That way you know that you reached the end.